# Auto convert all html char to readable text

Tags: javascript, html

I scraped webpage but it has a lot of special characters, for example,

"a +ΔS" turns into: "a +Î”S"

"→" turns into: "â†’"

"<−>" turns into: "<âˆ’>"

When I display it to my website.

I tried to change it manually to html numbers like "→" to "& rarr ;", but I feel like I am wasting my time because of too many occurences.

Why does his website reads "→" without converting to "& rarr ;"?

I tried this but did not work Thanks:

```
replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/g, function(i) {
   document.write('&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';');
});
```

Comment: The character encoding of the file conflicts with the character encoding specified in the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, now it works: <?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>